# "How to reinstall Windows?" - on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, question-quality

I'm talking about this question, [How to uninstall RHEL from a dual-boot system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3708/250). The title makes it look like a Linux question, but reading into the question at hand, and the (accepted) answer, I can't keep telling myself that the question should have been titled "How to reinstall Windows?". Am I feeling right?

Answer (score 4):

I think a 'How to recover windows when linux gets in the way' could also be a suitable title.

I would argue that this is on-topic as it is **NIX** that got in the way, and **NIX** that was used to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it was off-topic too when I saw it, but since *nix ended up being involved in the solution I guess I was wrong

Answer (score 2):

A better title could have been "How to remove GRUB" either way it's A grey area but I think would be OK here

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is one of those rare topics that would fit both here and [in MS's Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247804).